# What happens if a prometheus collector is not added to a registry?

Tags: go, prometheus

If I create a collector, for example a `Counter`, and never register it in either the global prometheus registry or in my own sub-registry, but I call `Inc()` on the counter, will my application incur any penalty (unbound memory consumption, panic, or otherwise)? A simple test passes with no error, but I'm unsure of any unknown consequences.

```
func TestUnregisteredCounter(t *testing.T) {
    processedCounters = prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: "namespace",
        Subsystem: "",
        Name:      "counters_processed",
        Help:      "Number of counters processed",
    })

    processedCounters.Inc()
}
```